# Delete Data from Gridview

Tags: vb.net, gridview

```
Protected Sub GridView1_RowDeleting(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewDeleteEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowDeleting
    Dim conn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection()
    Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand()
    conn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=PRGM\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=HRMS;Integrated Security=True"
    conn.Open()
    cmd = New SqlCommand("Delete from mst_emp where Emp_ID = @EmpID", conn)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmpID", SqlDbType.BigInt)
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    conn.Close()
End Sub
```

This is the code I have written. Still its not deleting. I'm using VB with SQL. Help me to Delete data from the gridview. Help me with the code and which event to write.

```
<asp:ButtonField CommandName="Delete" HeaderText="Delete" ShowHeader="True" Text="Delete" />
```

`TABLE mst_Emp 
    Emp_ID,
    Emp_FirstName,
    Emp_LastName,
    Emp_Address,
    Emp_ContactNo,
    Dept_ID (Foreign key),
    Marital_Status,
    Gender`

Comment: is the grid databound?

Comment: you should accept the answer from @Nocturnal as it is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't seem to be giving the @EmpID Value

change this

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmpID", SqlDbType.BigInt)
```

to this

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@EmpID", SqlDbType.BigInt).value = MyEmpID
```

MyEmpID should be your ID of course ^^

and btw cmd is initiated 2 x with new... once is enough ^^